# Registration form in SharePoint 2010

Tags: 2010

I'm looking to create a simple registration/sign up form in SharePoint 2010 without the use of Designer or code

simple name sign up - for internal users of the site only

Comment: You need to do customization. There is no OOTB for this. Do you need for external users or AD users?

Comment: For External Users you will need FBA

Comment: Just internal users. I've not much experience in using sharepoint so not even sure where to start for this

Comment: the resister is to be simple just for people to add their name to register for something and where i can remove if needed

Comment: You need to read about SPGroup and related articles for your understanding. Why do you need a form then?

Comment: Make sure to check SPGroup policy and for external users i agree with Gaurracs to use FBA